# Printing variant types in OCaml

Tags: printing, ocaml, variant

In my OCaml program, I spend considerable time wring "to_string" for variant types over and over again. Either I need them for debugging purpose, or because I need a specific formatted output.

So far, they follow a template such as follows:

```
let rec to_string = function                                                                                                               
    | Var x -> x                                                                 
    | Implies (f1, f2) -> Printf.sprintf "(=> %s %s)" (to_string f) (to_string f2)
    | And (f1, f2) -> Printf.sprintf "(& %s %s)" (to_string f1) (to_string f2)   
    | Or (f1, f2) -> Printf.sprintf "(| %s %s)" (to_string f1) (to_string f2)    
    | Not (f) -> Printf.sprintf "(~ %s)" (to_string f)                           
    | True -> "#t"                                                               
    | False ->"#f"
```

I'm wondering if there are more convenient/conventional ways of than this, possibly with the latest development of the language. For instance, automatic generation of templates based on the type? generic printing functions that could be used for debugging?

One way advocated in "Real World OCaml" is to use the Sexp module of the Core library that provides facilities for this very purpose. It seems to work well if you don't need much customization about how you print the values. I'd like to know if there are other/better options.

Comment: There's an camlp4 preprocessor which extends ocaml syntax with a new directive `deriving`, which among other things let you indicate if you want string conversion functions to be mechanically written for you. The syntax in reminiscent of Haskell's deriving (`deriving show`).

Comment: The library is [there](https://code.google.com/p/deriving/). Although I never used it I know it's *very good*. I am not sure if it is still usable with 4.0+ versions of Ocaml. (one of) the author has an excellent tutorial on camlp4, with [one chapter](http://ambassadortothecomputers.blogspot.fr/2010/03/reading-camlp4-part-5-filters.html?m=1)  describing how to develop such extension.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's the same as what is found in Core, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be similar to what is done in  Core. Basically, you can add "with sexp" after a type definition, and camlp4 derives for you conversion functions to and from Sexp.t (for which there are generic printing and parsing functions).

Comment: Ah right, I remember now: iirc `Sexp` goal is to provide symbolic expressions to ocaml (as in lisp I believe),  which are serializable in a human readable format. One side effect is that it makes it convenient for converting to strings.

Comment: Ideally, in this case, you would like to be able to list just the constructor name and the format string (`Implies -> "(=> %s %s)"`). Everything else is boiler-plait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're few type-based generators, that you may found interesting, like `deriving`, `typerep`, `sexplib`, etc. But I do not expect, that there is something magical, that will read your mind on compile time and write a pretty-printing functions according to your taste and feelings. What concerning templating, then all of the templating engines are some kind of pattern-matching, (usually stringly typed), and OCaml already provides you pattern-matching out of box. And also do not forget, that your type definition is recursive and this makes template based approaches much harder to use. You can use some automatic `json` or `xml` based dumper, like `ocaml-cow` and implement some kind of xslt transformation, but you will end up with lots of code, that are actually reinventing OCaml's native pattern matching.

So, for small languages, like yours, writing this `to_string` functions is the best solution. I think that this is the most natural way to express your idea to computer. I would also suggest to use `Format` module, and recurse using `%a` specifiers. Also, `Format` module, has concepts of `tags`. Tags allows to literally tag pieces of text in format strings,
the format of tagging can be explained with the following example:

```
@{<html>@{<head>@{<title>Tags!@}@}@{<body>Hello!@}@}
```

This can be automatically transferred to HTML:

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>
    Tags!
    </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   Hello!
   </body>
  </html>
```

One can also, transfer it to `LaTeX`, `json`, or anything else, including to nothing (i.e., ignoring tags at all).  But Tags are more about handling formatting and meta information, like syntax higlighting and referencing. They can't actually influence on concrete syntax.

For rich syntax trees the approach of writing recursive set of pretty-printing function doesn't scale well. And that's why there is O in the OCaml. You can use open recursion to implement AST-visitor clasess with lots of hooks (i.e., methods). This is the approach that is used in OCaml itself and camlp4.