# Printing enumerated and record types within an ocamldebug custom printer

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a custom printer for `Map` types for use in `ocamldebug`.  I would like to leverage the debugger's pretty printer for enumerated and record types within my custom printer.  Is this possible?

I've got a module, `m.mli`, with a couple of types, and I'm mapping integers to gammas:

```
type alpha = A | B
type gamma = { m: alpha }
module IMap : Map.S with type key = int
val print_map: gamma IMap.t -> unit
```

The implementation looks like so:

```
open Format

type alpha = A | B
type gamma = { m: alpha }

module IMap = Map.Make(struct 
  type t = int 
  let compare = (-) 
end)

let rec ig_pairs = function
  | [] -> ()
  | [(k,g)] ->
     open_hvbox 0;
     printf "%u->" k;
     print_break 0 2;
     print_string (stringifier_that_saves_my_ass g);
     close_box ()
  | (k,g)::xs ->
     open_hvbox 0;
     printf "%u->" k;
     print_break 0 2;
     print_string (stringifier_that_saves_my_ass g);
     print_string ",";
     close_box ();
     ig_pairs xs;
     ()

let print_map m =
  print_string "{";
  open_hvbox 0;
  ig_pairs (IMap.bindings m);
  close_box ();
  print_string "}"
```

And finally, I have `script.ml`:

```
open M

let key = 2
let some_gamma_value = { m = B }
let old = IMap.empty
let b = IMap.add key some_gamma_value old
```

Stepping through my script with `ocamldebug` (after stubbing `stringifier_that_saves_my_ass`),

1. I can `print some_gamma_value` to obtain a nice representation of `some_gamma_value` and
2. I can `load_printer m.cmo` and `install_printer print_map` to get something other than `<abstr>` out of `print b`.

I want `stringify_that_saves_my_ass` to provide the representation from (1) within my custom printer to facilitate printing map values.

Comment: Summary: as I understand it, you're asking for a way to call the default printer of ocamldebug from within a custom printer. This would be convenient, especially for types like `alpha`. I suspect it's not possible, or it would be documented. But I don't know for sure, so this is a comment rather than an answer :-)

Comment: I agree with your suspection.  When I asked I was pretty sure it was infeasible: I'm looking for somebody to prove us wrong.  Failing that, I'm looking  an alternative that doesn't involve rebuilding `ocamldebug`'s built in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Deriving](https://github.com/ocsigen/deriving) library provides preprocessors that build formatters for record and variant types automatically.  You just have to suffix the type `with show` (or `deriving (Show)`).  The generated formatters require that any contained types have been `with show`-suffixed also.  Given `type a = A | B with show`, the preprocessor generates a `module Show_a = ...` such that `Show_a.format: Format.formatter -> t -> unit`.  This `format` function is a good substitute for the debugger's pretty printer.

You can `with show`-suffix a `Map` also to save yourself the trouble of writing a `print_map` method.

Answer (score 0):

To be installed in ocamldebug or ocaml toplevel the printer need to have the following signature:

```
Format.formatter -> t -> unit
```

where `t` is the type you're goint to print.

That means, that your printer should also accept one more argument, namely formatter, i.e., an abstraction of a channel. In other words, instead of outputting just to standard output, you need to output to the specified channel. That means, that you need to use `fprintf` and `pp_` family of functions that accepts the formatter.

What concerning the `stringifier` problem, then since your map is polymorphic over the value type, you need to make your printers to be a functions from the printer that prints your value type into the printers that prints the whole map. This just means, that you need to add an extra parameter to your printer, namely `pp_value`, that will print the value type.

To demonstrate this in a full fledged example, take a look at this [Trie](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap_types/bap_trie.ml) (from which I forget to remove the debugging code) module,

```
let rec pp pp_val fmt t =
    let pp_some_data fmt = function
      | None -> ()
      | Some v -> fprintf fmt "data =@ %a@," pp_val v in
    let pp_table fmt cs =
      Tokens.iter cs (fun ~key ~data ->
          let toks = Key.sexp_of_token key in
          fprintf fmt "@[%a ->@ %a@]"
            Sexp.pp toks (pp pp_val) data) in
    fprintf fmt "{@;@[%a@ %a@]}@;"
      pp_some_data t.data pp_table t.subs
```

Tries are little bit more complex maps, so the printer reflects this, but let's go to the usage of the printer. But before we need to concretize our `Trie` to a particular key type, let it be `string`:

```
module String = Make(struct
    type t = string
    type token = char with bin_io, compare, sexp
    let length = String.length
    let nth_token = String.unsafe_get
    let token_hash = Char.to_int
  end)
```

Now let's print it. Again, we can print only concrete structures, so suppose that we're going to use `int Trie`, i.e., our value type is `int`. We create a printer for the `int` tries, and install it

```
let pp_int_trie = pp pp_print_int
#install_printer pp_int_trie;;
```

After that, all string tries with int value type will be printed, and here is the full example:

```
open String
let pp_int_trie = pp pp_print_int
let t = create ();;
add t "hell is my life" 1;;
add t "hello" 2;;
add t "hello my darling Clementine" 3;;
#install_printer pp_int_trie;;
t;;
```

I hope, that this will be enough, to get the idea.

Comment: This left me scratching my head as to where I got the idea that the printers signature should be `t -> unit`.  Rummaging around, I came back to the debugger's docs for `install_printer`: _Register the function named printer-name (a value path) as a printer for objects whose types match the argument type of the function_.  I've seen `t->unit` work, so maybe [this _old style_ versus _new style_ stuff](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.02/debugger/loadprinter.ml#L124-L129) is relevant--just guessing.

Comment: I'm looking for a `pp_value` function that recognizes enumerated and record types and pretty prints them similar to `ocamldebug`'s built in print method.

Comment: This is not very possible... toplevel pretty printers works, because this is bytecode, and toplevel have an access to source code. In general, when you're compiling, it is not possible to print, since all type information is removed. To overcome this, Core library require everyone to implement certain interface (and implements it for its own types), thus allowing for most of the types to be printed.

Comment: few threads, that you may find usefull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336244/ocaml-automate-custom-pretty-printer-installing/29337608#29337608
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527501/printing-variant-types-in-ocaml/28529576#28529576

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I had seen Deriving, but it looked dead.  Sexplib searches led me to the Oscigen fork of Deriving, which I ultimately used to solve my problem.  Thanks again.